# Baking side of pizza stone

Tags: pizza, pizza-stone

How do I tell which side of my pizza stone is the top side and is the side to bake a pizza on? I did not buy the stone but was given to me some years ago and I have not used it because I do not know which side I should put the pizza on and which side is not used to bake on.

Comment: The vast majority can be used either way.  Do you have pictures?

Comment: Thank you for your info and help. I do not have a photo but one side does have the Pfazgraff logo cut into it and since I have been reading that pizzas can stick to the stone I would imagine that the safest side to use would be the smooth side, especially since I have never used it to place a pizza directly on it to bake.

Answer (score 1):

Many pizza stones are double-sided, if so you can use either. If you have a big difference between the two surfaces then I suggest using the smoother one.

Pizza can stick like glue to a baking stone, if you liberally sprinkle fine cornmeal, or better yet medium ground semolina under the dough it will keep it from adhering to the surface.

Also be sure to pre-heat the oven a long time before baking to get the stone up to temperature. An inch of stone takes well oven an hour to be ready to bake on.

Comment: I so appreciate your info on pizza stones. Since one side of mine does have a logo imprinted on it and the other is smooth I will be using the smooth side. I have never used it to cook a pizza directly on it so now I know which side will be easier to use and clean if it should stick.

Answer (score 1):

Either way up will do as you don't actually have to cook on the stone, it's just thermal mass to keep you oven hotter for longer

Turn the oven all the way up to maximum, wait until you thermometer show no change in temperature. This may take about 30+ minutes depending on the stone/steel mass

Cook your pizza on your favourite metal tray/pan on a rack above the stone. Much easier clean-up, and same if not better results

Comment: Thank you so very much for your advice. I will certainly try cooking my pizzas this way.